# Uploading a file to a folder using JavaScript and then saving the filename into a variable

Tags: javascript, css, font-face

I want to let users upload their own font files(.woff files) to my website and was planning on then copying the name of the whole file(for an example: sans-seriff.woff) and putting that in the CSS with JavaScript, which will in turn change the whole font of the website.

So I wanted to ask how I can firstly make the upload function send the file to a specific location e.g. public/fonts/"sans-seriff.woff" And then when uploaded, how to save that into a variable in order to change that in the CSS as well.

Looking forward to your ideas and help! :)

Comment: You didn't mention anything about the server side code you are using. Here's an example with PHP and pure JS on the client side: https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Ajax-JavaScript-file-upload-example

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.